# Getting float value from integers

Tags: c, objective-c, iphone

How can I get a float or real value from integer division?  For example:

```
double result = 30/233;
```

yields zero.  I'd like the value with decimal places.

How can I then format so only two decimal places display when used with a string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just add a decimal to either the numerator or the denominator:

```
double result = 30.0 / 233;
double result = 30 / 233.0;
```

Typecasting either of the two numbers also works.

As for the second part of the question, if you use printf-style format strings, you can do something like this:

```
sprintf(str, "result = %.2f", result);
```

Bascially, the ".2" represents how many digits to output after the decimal point.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure how to use that with the char* but this works just as well [NSString stringWithFormat:@"result = %.2f", result].

Comment: Yeah, that's the great thing about Cocoa—there are a lot of places where printf-style formatted strings are utilized (NSLog being the most prominent of them all, I'd say).

Comment: Just be careful about subtle differences, like the %s being encoded as the system encoding rather than whatever the current encoding calls for and %S being a big-endian UTF-16 string instead of wchar_t.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an integer (not integer constant):

```
int i = 20;
int j = 220;
double d = i/(double)j;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to do what you are trying to achieve, I think..

```
double result = 30/233.0f;
```

for iOS development (iPhone/iPad/etc) better to use float type.

```
float result = 30/233.0f;
```